# "marry his daughter" vs. "married his daughter"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Why did the rich man let John marry his daughter?

vs

> Why did the rich man let John married his daughter?

What the different in meaning between these 2 questions?

Comment: The second one means the speaker doesn’t know English very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do we use zero infinitives with make, let, have?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443192/why-do-we-use-zero-infinitives-with-make-let-have)

Comment: Please read through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for more tips on formatting questions. Also, [this is not a discussion forum](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), so please don't ask follow-on questions in answers. [Be as detailed as you can](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) in your initial question, so there is less chance you will need to ask a follow on question like, "Which one is better?" Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, in the sense that only one has a meaning to speak of. One is a correct, standard sentence, and the other is incorrect according to the generally understood grammar of any dialect with which I am familiar.

The indirect object of this sense of *let*, or similar senses of *make* or *have* (and some others) is a *bare infinitive phrase*. That means that it uses the infinitive form of the verb, without *to*, but has its own object(s), adverbs, prepositional phrases etc. It can create ambiguity with prepositional phrases - it can be unclear if they apply to *let* etc. or to the verb in the object.

Do not use the second question. It will make it clear that you don't know English very well.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the "Why did" part of the sentences makes all of the actions (actions are the verbs for things that a person did) automatically be descriptions of things in the past, so you don't have to use the past tense for those.  People who are used to reading English might find the second sentence strange and confusing because of that.  The first sentence is better.

Comment: That *did* certainly puts the main verb (*let*) into the past tense, but there's a more overriding reason why *marry* is in the present tense that would apply if another past tense were used, like "he has let John marry..." or "he let John marry...".